# Can't start TOR on freshly upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 (from 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu

That is what `service tor@default status` says:

```
● tor@default.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor@default.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Вт 2017-05-09 00:37:37 MSK; 10s ago
  Process: 4184 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -Z -m 02755 -o debian-tor -g debian-tor -d /var/run/tor (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

май 09 00:37:37 redkin-server systemd[1]: Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
май 09 00:37:37 redkin-server systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Unit entered failed state.
май 09 00:37:37 redkin-server systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
май 09 00:37:37 redkin-server systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
май 09 00:37:37 redkin-server systemd[1]: Stopped Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
май 09 00:37:37 redkin-server systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
май 09 00:37:37 redkin-server systemd[1]: Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
```

Here is the line from syslog:

```
 23:40:25 redkin-server systemd[20127]: tor@default.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/bin/install: Invalid argument
```

`lsof -i :9050` shows nothing. Where to should I dig?

P.S. Forgot to mention: before upgrade TOR worked fine.

Comment: Running Debian here, the only reference to `/usr/bin/install` I could find is in `/lib/systemd/system/tor@default.service`: `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -Z -m 02755 -o debian-tor -g debian-tor -d /var/run/tor`. Can you post how it looks like in Ubuntu. You could also try to execute the install command manually and see if it works when you remove one of the parameters.

Comment: Might be related to the bug reported [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=792187) and [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/567).

Comment: searching for /install I can find only the command line shown above in the log. It is equal to yours. Running it from bash doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Thank you Peter, Looks like it's realy systemd Issue. Indeed on my system /var/run was a symlink to /run. Unfortunately neither changing it to ../run nor adding ReadWRiteDirectories=-/run helped. Only if I cooment out ReadOnlyDirectories=/ the service starts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Peter Gerber noted, that was an issue with systemd.
What I've done:

- Changed symlink `/var/run` to point to `../run` instead of `/run`
- Added `ReadWriteDirectories=-/run` to `/lib/systemd/system/tor@default.service`
- After every change run `systemctl daemon-reload`

These two changes separately didn't help, but both of it combined resolved my problem. Thank you Peter once more!